# laravel model method to check a condition like hasRole(['admin','superadmin')?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, models, role

I'm trying laravel authorization and i need a method on User model that checks an condition and return boolean!
for example?

```
$user->hasRole(['superadmin']); // should return true/false
```

and in the model:

```
class User extends Model{
    /*****
    *****
    *****/
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function hasRole($roles)
    {
        // some validation and return boolean
    }
}
```

How do i do this via laravel Models? Is any way?

Comment: @BaikHo, that would create a never ending loop...

Comment: You ask How do I do this via laravel models but you already seem to have figured that out.  Just put in your logic...

Answer (score 1):

```
public function hasRole($roles)
{
    return !$this->roles->pluck('role_column')->intersect($roles)->isEmpty();
}
```

Don't forget to change 'role_column'

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of strings, and I assume your roles have names, you could do this with a simple sql query.

```
public function hasRole($roles) {
    return $this->roles->whereIn('role', $strings)->exists();
}
```